# Array of functions where i-th element returns i

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Yesterday my friend challenged me to write a function in C which would return an array of function pointers where i-th function would return i.
It is easy to get a similar effect in C++, but I am not sure how to do it in C.

Can anyone help me with that?

Edit.

The effect that I am looking for is something equivalent to this.

```
vector <function<int()>> get_functions(int n) {
    vector <function<int()>> functions;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        functions.emplace_back([i]() {
            return i;
        });
    }
    return functions;
}


int main() {
    auto functions = get_functions(10);
    for (auto f:functions) {
        cout << f() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit.

As asked in the comment section I provide my poor attempt on the challenge.

```
typedef int (*fun_t)(void);

int fun() { return 0; }
int fun1() { return 1; }

fun_t *get_functions() {
    fun_t *functions = malloc(sizeof(fun_t) * 2);

    functions[0] = fun;
    functions[1] = fun1;

    return functions;
}

int main() {
    fun_t* funs=get_functions();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n",funs[i]());
    }
    free(funs);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write the function for you, that your friend challenged you to write?

Comment: Yes he doesn't know the answer either :(

Comment: you are cheating

Comment: I would rephrase your question: show the C++ code, show your attempted C code, and then ask whether people can help finalising the C code (or show that it's indeed not possible in C).

Comment: ok  fair enough just wait a second

Comment: Also: if I understand the problem statement correctly: this can certainly be done in C. Possibly with some macros.

Comment: Ok here you have the C++ implementation  @9769953

Comment: Do you have any attempt at your C implementation; that would be a really good start to help.

Comment: I do have simple ones, if it were 2 functions :) like int fun1(){ return 1;} int fun2(){return 2;}  I don't think it is worth sharing , but if you want to I can add them to the post :)

Comment: Your friend is cheating: `function<int()>` is not a function pointer, it's a class, carrying a significant amount of context. An equivalent C code would build an array of structs holding context, and provide a single function that would take a pointer to such a struct (an equivalent of `this`). If the challenge is meant to prove that C++ offers more syntactic sugar, then I can only say - well duh!

Comment: @9769953 here you have my attempts

Comment: With Windows 3.1 you'd use PrestoChangeSelector.to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ code is cheating. `function<int()>` is not a function pointer; in fact, it's not a pointer at all, it's a class.

Therefore the equivalent C code would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// function<int ()>, simplified version just for this task
typedef struct {
    int (*code)(int);
    int ctx;
} function_int_t;

// function<int()>::operator()()    
int call(function_int_t fun) {
    return fun.code(fun.ctx);
}

// lambda body
int proto(int ctx) {
    return ctx;
}

function_int_t *get_functions(size_t n) {
    function_int_t *functions = calloc(n, sizeof *functions);
    if (!functions) {
        abort();  // hey, that's how C++ does it
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        functions[i] = (function_int_t){ proto, i };  // capture i
    }
    return functions;
}

int main(void) {
    size_t n = 10;
    function_int_t *functions = get_functions(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", call(functions[i]));
    }
    free(functions);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution